# I want to get an exact time from a fetched ISO8610 string in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, weather

```js
async function get(input, apikey){
    const firstRequest = await fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/autocomplete?apikey=${apikey}&q=${input}`);
    const firstData = await firstRequest.json();
    const value = firstData[0].Key;
    const secondRequest = await fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/${value}?apikey=${apikey}&details=true`);
    const secondData = await secondRequest.json();        

    return secondData[0]
}



document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const apikey = 'JmOpzCCKrupaANLa2xTGH73ZG3pBiAbx';
    const input = document.getElementById('inp').value;
    const label = document.getElementById('lbl');

    document.getElementById('inp').value = '';
    
    get(input, apikey)
        .then(data => {
            const date = new Date(data.LocalObservationDateTime);
            const time = date.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit'
            });

            label.textContent = time;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

})
```

```css
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}

#lbl{
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(212, 38, 145);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

#inp{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#btn{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 110%;
    padding: 6px 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <label for="inp" id="lbl">Time</label>
        <input type="text" id="inp">
        <button type="button" id="btn">Get Info</button>
    </div>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After fetching an ISO1806 string from Accuweather API, I want it to update the textContent of the Label. But the time does not matches the system time/local time in my region or if I try to fetch any other region's time then it also does not matches that particular regions local time and have a slight difference. I want a solution to this but in pure Vanilla JavaScript and not from any other Date or Time library.[You can refer to the snapshot I am attaching here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUqP7.jpg).[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Kop.png)
[And you can see here the result what I meant when anyone fetches any location's data from https://www.accuweather.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpisD.png)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that. The "*[DateTime of the current observation](https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-current-conditions-api/apis/get/currentconditions/v1/{locationKey})*" is just 8 minutes ago, which is very good! If you say that this delay is consistent for all over the world (which seems very unlikely), it could be that the server time of the reporting server, or your local client's time are off and you should synchronise with an internet time service.

Comment: but if you notice the other image (from https://www.accuweather.com/) I've linked, you can see there is no difference in the time of my machine and the time displayed below the "current weather". why it is so?
I have checked it by changing different locations and matched their exact time on Google....and it showed the same time without any difference..I don't understand why the same API is showing different time in ISO string and different in website.

Comment: I don't know - you'd have to look into the code of the website for that! Maybe they're lying and claiming to have more recent data than their own API returns. They don't use an JS API call on their website, but just provide server-side-rendered content, so we can't know.